# There is no user file in home directory

Tags: home-directory

I started using Ubuntu yesterday. Since then I've just been trying to get the Anaconda Python distro working with Vim and am thus far unsuccessful. In Vim I managed to create a file called vimrc and edited it to have vundle installed. Now I'm trying to add the vim-conda plugin and apparently I need to manually edit the vimrc file again (leading me to wander what the point of vundle is). Apparently it's in home/neil. But when I click the file button on the left of the screen and it goes to home, there is no file there called neil. Where is it? Also, why do files not show up when I click the "search" thing top left?

Comment: To see `/home/neil` run `cd /`, then `ls | grep home`. You see the `/home`, Then go in with `cd /home`. Now do `ls` when there and you will see `neil` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing on the `Home` button sends you to your *Home*, which in your case is the folder `/home/neil`

You won't find `neil` inside `home/neil`, but you'll find all files in this folder.

In order to show hidden files you should press <kbd>CTRL H</kbd> (or go to *View* -> *Show Hidden Files* Menu)

Comment: Didn't know there were hidden folders. Okay I found it now, thanks!

Comment: All files which starts with `dot`, e.g. `.vimrc` are called *hidden files*

Comment: Will do when it allows me to. At 7 mins.